# Why is the getWidth giving an issue and not getHeight in Log?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have the following code:

`Log.i("IX GETX and GETY", " " + f.getWidth()-iv.getWidth() + " " + f.getHeight()-iv.getHeight());`

I get the following error: `The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int`

Both the getWidth and getHeight have the same calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your calculations with parenthesis, as seen below:

```
Log.i("IX GETX and GETY", " " + (f.getWidth()-iv.getWidth()) + " " + (f.getHeight()-iv.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Weird, that worked fine! Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Also, I believe this occurs due to it trying to remove `iv.getWidth()` from your concatenated string ` <value of f.getWidth()`.

Comment: Glad I could help @SiKni8, and don't forget to accept the answer on your way out. :)